# Not able to create proper JSON using Java

Tags: java, json

My situation is crazy. I'm creating a JSON object, which is perfectly fine from server side end. But, this is not getting acceptable due to extra " which is created via server side. My server side code is

```
String id = "123";
    String hql = "FROM Person E WHERE E.userId = "+id;
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List<?> results = query.list();     
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        Personalisation p = (Personalisation) results.get(i);
        obj.put("courseId", p.getCourseId());
        obj.put("CourseValue", p.getCourseValue());
    }
    System.out.println(obj);
```

It is printing

```
{"CourseValue":"{\"color\": \"green\",\"value\": \"#f00\"}","courseId":"C5"}
```

This is fine from server side end. You could see extra " before {\"color tag, when I try to parse the same thing on client side, it doesnt accept due to illegal character. What should I need to do?

Here is the fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/hLkUz/43/

Answer (score 4):

`p.getCourseValue()` seems to return a String containing JSON:

```
{"color": "green","value": "#f00"}
```

Now when you put this into `JSONObject` and serialize the object it will escape the JSON string again.

Instead of putting the course value as JSON tring into the `JSONObject` you need to build up the course value object yourself.

Comment: I tried it using new JSONObject(p.getCourseValue()). Still its not accepting. Any info?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you cannot parse a JSON object as a string so
use

```
 System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(obj);
```

Comment: and use 
`obj.put("CourseValue", new JSONObject(p.getCourseValue()));`

while inserting

Comment: Its not accepting new JSONObject(p.getCourseValue()). It says remove argument

Comment: and I'm not worried about SOP. I'm worried because its not being accepted by client

Comment: give a try to  `(JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(p.getCourseValue());`

Comment: Yeah I tried by new JsonParser().parse(p.getCourseValue()).getAsJsonObject()

Comment: modified your jsfiddle to work..but not an appropirate way
 
`var string = '{"CourseValue":"{\"color\": \"green\",\"value\": \"#f00\"}","courseId":"C5"}';
string=string.replace(/\"\{/g,'{').replace(/\}\"/g,'}');
console.log(string);
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(obj);

`

Answer (score 0):

Able to construct by using

```
new JsonParser().parse(p.getCourseValue()).getAsJsonObject()
```